# Using Sessions or Cookies with a Get Value

Tags: php, session, get

I get a field value using GET from a URL.
www.test.com?id=12345

I create a session using assigning the id to a variable.

```
$id= $_GET['id'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['mainid'] = $id;

if(isset($_SESSION['mainid'])) {
  echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['mainid']; }
```

I then use echo session on other pages

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mainid'])) {
  echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['mainid']; }
```

The problem is when i go back to the home page, it tries to look for the get value $id, and it is blank now as the URL doesn't contain the Feild value id=12345. How do i get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['mainid'])){
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['mainid'] = $id;
} elseif(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_SESSION['mainid'])) {
      if($_GET['id'] != $_SESSION['mainid'] ) 
       {
          $_SESSION['mainid'] = $_GET['id'];
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Ray , This works great until the id changes. So for example the session starts and $_SESSION['mainid'] is assigned the value 12345 , but now if the url changes to www.test.com?id=54677 , it doesn't change or assign the new value to the seesion.

Comment: @user3485335 Did you check with the modified code? It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should rewrite your code for sure to check if the variable exists first and then start the session.

Something like this should do.

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
if ($id) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['mainid'] = $id;
}
```

Comment: Hi @rsz , This works great until the id changes. So for example the session starts and $_SESSION['mainid'] is assigned the value 12345 , but now if the url changes to www.test.com?id=54677 , it doesn't change or assign the new value to the seesion.

Comment: I don't see why it should not assign it. I tried it just now, and it rewrites the session mainid like expected

Answer (score 0):

Just put your below code

```
$id= $_GET['id'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['mainid'] = $id;
```

inside isset

Your code should look something like below code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

     $id= $_GET['id'];

     session_start();
     $_SESSION['mainid'] = $id;
}
```